# Can we use $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT'] to get a reliable process time?

Tags: php, execution-time, time-measurement

I see every one suggests using a variable such as

```
$start_time = microtime(TRUE);
```

on top of the script, and then on the final line we do:

```
$process_time = microtime(TRUE) - $start_time;
```

My question is, can we reliably use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT']` and skip the $start_time altogether? if so, why does every one still suggest using $start_time on top?

Example of what I mean:

```
<?php
// No need for $start_time...

// All the stuff we do to have the benchmark at the end

// Only this line needed to display execution time
echo "Processed in: ". bcsub(microtime(TRUE), "{$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT']}", 4);
?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Measuring the time of PHP scripts - Using $\_REQUEST\['REQUEST\_TIME'\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28703822/measuring-the-time-of-php-scripts-using-requestrequest-time)

Comment: @ChrisWhite Thank you, but it doesn't answer my questions and doubts

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It depends on what you're trying to measure.

`$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT']` is set the moment your webserver [hands the processing over](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54193511/1941241) to PHP. That means it will always be the timestamp PHP starts processing the request. So if you want to measure how long it took PHP to get to a specific point, you can use that. The downside is that you don't really know what PHP is doing before it gets to your code. There may be files in PHP's `auto-prepend` configuration that take up processing time before it even reads the first line of your code. But if you actually *want* to measure that time as well, you *have* to use this property.

On the other hand, you can ask for `microtime(true)` whenever you want, which helps when you want to measure the performance of a *specific piece of code*. For example, maybe you're in an MVC framework and you only want to measure how long it's taking your model to fetch and prepare a database resultset and you don't really care how long it took the framework to figure out which controller/action needed to be called or how long it took your controller to ask your model for information.

Comment: This line explained it perfectly for me: `The downside is that you don't really know what PHP is doing before it gets to your code` , Thanks!

Comment: $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT'] is filled BEFORE auto-prepend is processed

Comment: @paranoiq Correct. That's what I meant with the last line of the first paragraph. To rephrase that: "if you want to include any time spent in auto-prepend in your measurements, you *have* to use the REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT property".